# How can I realize font-size depending on elements total width?

Tags: angularjs

My task is to realize font-size changing depending on elements width in my AngularJS application. My HTML code is:

```html
<div id="widthToCompareWidth" class="total">
      <div class="total-row">
        <div class="total-cell">
          <div font-size-from-width="0" class="total-cell-wrap">
            <div translate="TOTAL_1" class="total-label"></div>
            <div class="total-value-wrap"><span ng-bind="ctrl.total1" class="total-value"></span></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="total-cell">
          <div font-size-from-width="1" class="total-cell-wrap">
            <div translate="TOTAL_2" class="total-label"></div>
            <div class="total-value-wrap"><span ng-bind="ctrl.total2" class="total-value"></span></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="total-cell">
          <div font-size-from-width="2" class="total-cell-wrap">
            <div translate="TOTAL_3" class="total-label"></div>
            <div class="total-value-wrap"><span ng-bind="ctrl.total3" class="total-value"></span></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="total-cell">
          <div font-size-from-width="3" class="total-cell-wrap">
            <div translate="TOTAL_4" class="total-label"></div>
            <div class="total-value-wrap"><span ng-bind="ctrl.total4"></span></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

The idea is to compare the sum of widths of all elements with class 'total-cell-wrap' to the width of parent block with class 'total'. I'm using the following code in my controller:

```js
var widthToCompareWidth = document.getElementById('widthToCompareWidth').offsetWidth;

        $scope.offsetsArray = [
            0, 0, 0, 0
        ];
        $scope.changeFont = false;

        $scope.$watchCollection('offsetsArray', function (newVal, oldVal) {
            if(newVal !== oldVal) {
                var totalAmount = $scope.offsetsArray.reduce(function (sum, curr) {
                    if(!sum) sum = 0;
                    if(!curr) curr = 0;
                    return sum + curr;
                }, 0);
                (totalAmount > widthToCompareWidth) ? $scope.changeFont = true : $scope.changeFont = false;
            }
        })
```

And added following directive:

```js
(function () {
    "use strict";

    angular
        .module('app')
        .directive('fontSizeFromWidth', fontSizeFromWidth);

    function fontSizeFromWidth() {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: {
                fontSizeFromWidth: "=fontSizeFromWidth"
            },
            link: linkFn,
        };

        function linkFn(scope, element, attr, controller) {

            scope.$watch(function () {
                return scope.elementWidth = element[0].offsetWidth;
            }, function(value) {
                scope.$parent.offsetsArray[scope.fontSizeFromWidth] = scope.elementWidth;
            });

            scope.$watch('$parent.changeFont', function (newValue, oldValue) {
                if(oldValue === false && newValue === true) {
                    element[0].classList.add('total-24');
                } else if(oldValue === true && newValue === false) {
                    if(element[0].classList.contains('total-24')) {
                        element[0].classList.remove('total-24');
                    }
                }
            });

            element.bind('load resize', function () {
                scope.$apply();
            });

        }
    }

})();
```

Actually, 'total-24' class adds smaller font-size to block.

It seems to work, but not exactly correctly - because there is ton of errors in console, connected to $watch, as I understand:

Uncaught Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: ...

So, question is - what am I doing wrong, and what is the right way to do this?

My AngularJS version is 1.5.8.

Comment: Are you sure you want that? :-) normally you shouldn't introduce too many different font-sizes on your website, bad design. But maybe you've a good use case for it :-) To be more on-topic: did you consder using font-scaling based on viewport? like vw, vh, vi, vb etc

Comment: Thank you for your advise. But my case is that those 4 'total-cell' divs will contain numbers, that can be small or big, 10 or 1000000000, and the idea is, that we don't know which number will the account have. So we decided to make different font-sizes... actually, only 2 ones are supposed to use- 34 and 24 px. It's a good idea with vw's, but using it, font-size of big numbers is too small even on 1920px viewport.